# What is the best way to embed a SoundCloud widget in react-native-webview?

Tags: react-native, iframe, soundcloud, react-native-webview

So basically as the title suggests. I have a `react-native-webview` component in my app and I want it to show a SoundCloud player via the SoundCloud [widget](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget). I also want to use the available methods exposed by the widget API (for example `getDuration`), add listeners to events, etc. I have tried 2 approaches to accomplish this, but each approach ends with a different issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

**Option 1:**

The `source` prop that I pass to the `WebView` is a static HTML string:

```
<html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <iframe
            id="sound-cloud-iframe"
            src="${finalUri}"
          >
          </iframe>
        </body>
      </html>
```

That works well with the API and everything, but I can't seem to make it look good on-screen. It looks like this:

[image]

The red border marks the `WebView` component. I want the video to take up that entire space, which I can do with setting the `width` & `height` attributes of the `iframe` to 100%. The problem is, that when I do that, the elements inside the iframe retain their size (e.g the track/artist name, the progress bar at the bottom, etc). See here:
[image]

If I could somehow make it all scale by the same proportions, that would be amazing. Injecting JS scripts that scale each and every element individually seems like a bad solution.

**Option 2:**

The `source` prop that I pass to the `WebView` is a SoundCloud link, for example:

```
source={{uri: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F94546771&show_artwork=true}}
```

That makes the video player look just right:

[image]

But, it won't allow me to use the API exposed by SoundCloud. The reason is that, as mentioned in their API reference, there needs to be some `iframe` element that I need to to pass into `SC.Widget` in order to be able to use all the methods and listeners that I need. There is no `iframe` here! The HTML content that renders inside the `WebView` is actually the exact inner document that would render inside the `iframe` if I used the static HTML that I put in Option 1. If I could make the API work like that somehow, that would be amazing.

So, basically, I'm wondering which option presents the more-easily-solved issue, if they're solvable at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, used this static HTML:

```
<html>
        <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <iframe
            id="sound-cloud-iframe"
            src="${finalUri}"
            scrolling="no"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
          >
          </iframe>
        </body>
      </html>
```

The `meta` tag was the key to success here (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)